# Minimum numbers in the input before you can submit?

Tags: html, forms

I want a input where you first need to put 16 numbers before you can submit. Also the maximum is 16.

Code what I tried?

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
First name: <input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="FirstName" min="16" maxlength="16" value="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want 16 digits (not numbers) before you submit, so you'll need to validate with javascript.  Check you've got 16 digits, check you've got exactly 16 of them, return it as a boolean and away you go.

```
$("input[type='submit']").submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var re = /\d{16}/; 
  var res = !! str.match(re) && str.length == 16;
  if (res === true) { // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Like what?  There is nothing at that link.  Please provide your code here or on something like CodePen.